# Style Symfony2 Form Validation Popups

Tags: php, validation, symfony

I'm wondering how i can give the symfony form validation popups a custom style.

This popup shows up, if an input field is required and not filled.

[image]

Comment: This is not from your Symfony, its Google chrome default error layout for HTML5 input tags (required, email) and etc..
Its different in Firefox for example.. If you want to make custom errors you can use Jquery error validation plugin and customize your error layouts

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this has nothing to do with Symfony itself.

Those popups are the default popups which appear if your input is set to required but empty. They differ from browser to browser.
In your case you're using Chrome I guess?

```
<input type="text" id="isRequired" required="required">
```

Means the input is required and will show this message if it's empty on submit.
Also see [here](http://caniuse.com/form-validation) for browser support. It was introduced in HTML5

Watch [this demo](http://www.wufoo.com/html5/attributes/09-required.html) for another example.

> The required attribute marks any input/textarea as being required to have a value before the form can be submitted.

Comment: Naw...Symfony can do a lot of cool stuff :D This happens to everyone sometimes